# Convertir horas a minutos

Tags: jquery, datetime, timer

Quisiera  convertir un dato en formato `horas` en minutos utilizando `JQuery`

Dato a convertir

```
  var hora='3:19:00';
```

resultado

> ```
>   var nuevoDato= '199';
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una manera diferente de hacerlo sería usar las fechas de JavaScript, aunque **no es ideal** porque tiene bastantes limitaciones. Por ejemplo: el formato del texto debe ser *perfecto* (siguiendo el patrón `hh:mm:ss`) y las horas deben ser válidas (no se pueden tener más de 23 horas o 59 minutos).

La idea sería usar un objeto de tipo `Date` para parsear y trabajar con el tiempo:

```js
// hora a convertir
var t = "03:19:00";

// creamos una fecha genérica con tu tiempo
var d = new Date("0001-01-01T"+t);

// calculamos los minutos a partir de las horas y minutos de la fecha creada
var minutos = d.getHours() * 60 + d.getMinutes();

console.log(minutos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes separar las partes con split y hacer el cálculo a partir de ahí:

```js
//dato a convertir
var hora='3:19:00';

// Dividir en partes
var parts = hora.split(':');

// Calcular minutos (horas * 60 + minutos)
var total = parseInt(parts[0]) * 60 + parseInt(parts[1]);
  
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

con la opción de split de java script usted separa los datos por minutos,segundo y horas y realizar la conversión

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var pizza = "02:34:56";
var porciones = pizza.split(':');
document.write(porciones[0]);
document.write(porciones[1]);
document.write(porciones[2]); 
</script>
```